# SubMonth() no funciona como debería

Tags: laravel, carbon

Estoy tratando de obtener el mes anterior a la fecha actual utilizando el metodo de Carbon subMonth(), estaba funcionando bien antes, pero en esta fecha actual que es 29/03/2021 si le aplico el metodo me devuelve el mismo mes actual. Es decir que si estamos en el mes de marzo y le resto un mes me sigue devolviendo Marzo.

Lo que trato de hacer con esto es obtener el mes de Febrero en este caso y poder utilizarlo mas adelante en otras partes de mi código.

Alguien sabe el por que?

Esta el la fecha actual:

"2021-03-29T14:15:36.632393Z"

Este es el fragmento de codigo:

```
$mesAtras = Carbon::now()->subMonth();
    return $mesAtras;
```

Esta es la respuesta:

"2021-03-01T14:11:10.636668Z"

Comment: Creo que es porque el mes anterior de Febrero llego hasta el día 28 y al tratar de consultarlo en esta fecha que es día 29 es como si ese mes no hubiera existido, pero aun no se como arreglarlo.

Comment: @BetaM así es, justo ahora me he fijado.

Comment: Lo he arreglado poniendo el  firstOfMonth() antes de subMonth para buscar en el primer día del mes anterior.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Como el problema es que la fecha actual es 29/03/2021 al restarle un mes trataría de obtener la fecha 29/02/2021 la cual no existe y por tanto me devuelve la misma fecha actual.

Para solucionarlo solo agregue el método firstofMonth() que busca el primer día del mes antes de que se reste el mes.

Queda de esta manera:

```
$mesAtras = Carbon::now()->firsofMonth()->subMonth();
return $mesAtras;
```

Obteniendo la fecha 01/02/2021.

Answer (score 1):

Daré una respuesta tomando como punto de partida el aporte del buen [Matt Stauffer en Twitter](https://twitter.com/stauffermatt/status/1376699768328630272) que expone como solución algo como lo siguiente:

```
now()->subMonthsNoOverflow(1);
```

Cuya salida sería:

```
>>> now()->subMonthsNoOverflow(1);
=> Illuminate\Support\Carbon @1614482234 {#3205
     date: 2021-02-28 03:17:14.063605 UTC (+00:00),
   }
>>>
```

Aunque en realidad como se expone la propia [documentación](https://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/#api-addsub), tienes ese mismo método pero en singular que no requiere le pases algún valor entero directamente como argumento y sustraerá un mes a la fecha actual, del modo siguiente:

```
now()->subMonthNoOverflow();
```

Con esta salida:

```
=> Illuminate\Support\Carbon @1614482234 {#3205
     date: 2021-02-28 03:17:14.063605 UTC (+00:00),
   }
```

Por cierto y aunque no directamente relacionado a la pregunta he de comentarte que esta sintaxis es innecesaria:

```
Carbon::now();
```

Pues el [helper `now()`](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/helpers#method-now) te da acceso a una instancia de la clase *`Carbon`*

Comment: Entonces retorna el mes anterior con el ultimo dia? Y desde que version de laravel esta disponible?

Comment: No es tema de Laravel @JuanRivera si no de Carbon

Comment: Entonces con mi primera pregunta siempre devuelve el mes anterior con el ultimo dia?

Comment: Cuando es un escenario como el que plantea el OP que el mes anterior termina en 28 si

Comment: Si no lo es, entonces simplemente se resta el mes no? Si hoy es abril 30, entonces el mes anterior seria marzo 30